# Is it possible to fill PDF fields with HTML using PDFTK?

Tags: pdftk

I am using PDFTK to fill in PDF fields based on user input, then flatten the PDF.

I have a requirement to add HTML fields so that the user input can be formatted with e.g. bold, lists, etc., and the flattened PDF will show the fields as such, rather than what it currently does which is show the HTML code.

Is this possible? It may also be acceptable to convert the HTML to RTF if PDFTK can take RTF and display it formatted once the PDF is flattened.